# How to install MS sql server client in 64 bit windows 7 operating system?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server

I want to install sql server client in my windows 7 64 bit version. But I am unable to do that please provide some help. 
i want to install only Client not sql server. is this possible.

Comment: Which client are you talking about? SQL Server Native Client, other APIs (e.g. for ODBC or OLE-DB), or some program that would let you browse the data interactively (e.g. MS Access)?

Comment: Using my psychic abilities, I assume OP means Client Tools.

Comment: ya i want to install sql server native client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the SQL Server management studios.  Download SQL Server Express (the whole thing) and at setup, it will ask which components you would like to install. The components are split into two lists.  The top list is the server instance.

The bottom components are the ones you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

I've had no problems installing the Feature Pack for SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 7 Systems.  It can be obtained from Microsoft here:

[SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978)

The feature pack contains the SQL Server Native Client.  This client should be backwards compatible with previous SQL server versions (2005, 2008).